# Get count and percentage: match of group

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have a collection like this with `user` ids and `process_name`:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user    |             process_name             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 12      |                  a                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 12      |                  b                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 34      |                  c                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 36      |                  a                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 36      |                  d                   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 12      |                  p                   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

and we would like to get the number of specific processes (here: `a` and `b`) used by users, and their percentage in regard to the total process applied by the user.

For user `12` this would be 2 and (2/3 = 0,66) while for user `36` it would be 1 with 1/2 = 0,5.

So, for `db.processes.aggregate`, I guess we would definetly need a group for users:

```
$group : {
    _id : "$user",
    total : { $sum : 1 }
}
```

and a match for the `process_name`s:

```
$match : {
    "process_name" : {
        $in: ["a", "b"]
    }
}
```

However, it feels like a chicken-and-egg problem, because after matching I can't retrieve the number of total processes per users anymore. In contrast, after grouping I can't access `process_name`s anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following,

1. `$group` to get total of user, put the `process_name` to array
2. get the `$size` of array which includes **a** or **b**
3. get the percentage using `$divide`

And mongo query

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      users: {
        $addToSet: "$process_name"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      size_ab: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$users",
            cond: {
              $in: [
                "$$this",
                [
                  "a",
                  "b"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user: "$_id",
      percentage: {
        $divide: [
          "$size_ab",
          "$total"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PPYbRX32GVV)

Comment: you can use single combined pipeline like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/TKhf-445xzt , you can update your answer if you want.

Comment: Yes, i felt like he is the beginner, so he might not understand when we feed at once

Comment: @turivishal actually I've started mongodb 3 months back. I'm also a newbie, but I try to earn knowledge by answering, and I got a lot. So sometimes i may be wrong in some places.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with aggregtion

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOKcRYgaxuo)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {//Group by user, count the Total unique processes
      "_id": "$user",
      "processes": {
        "$addToSet": "$process"
      },
      "user": {
        $first: "$user"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {//Count the matched processes 
      matchCount: {
        $size: {
          "$setIntersection": [
            [
              "a",
              "b"
            ],
            "$processes"
          ]
        }
      },
      "totalCount": {
        $size: "$processes"
      },
      "user": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {//Percentage calculation
      "user": 1,
      "percentage": {
        "$divide": [
          "$matchCount",
          "$totalCount"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

//You can definitely use `$round` to reduce to the required decimals.